# Can upstart's "service start" be used inside a cron job?

Tags: linux, cron, upstart

> **TLDR**; Is it possible to create a cron job that runs *service*
>   *service_name* *start*? How?

Content of my

```
sudo crontab -e
```

is:

```
45 23 * * * service bormarise_celery_daemon start
```

This runs normally on terminal as root or server:

```
service bormarise_celery_daemon start
start: Job is already running: bormarise_celery_daemon
```

But cron gave the following error instead:

```
bormarise_celery_daemon: unrecognized service
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## tl;dr

You need to add `/sbin` to cron's `PATH` so the `service` script can find `initctl`. To do that, add a definition like this to the top of your crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

You may still run into issues with `cron` emailing you since `initctl` exits with status 1 (fail) if the job you try to start is already running. You could get around that with something like:

```
45 23 * * * service bormarise_celery_daemon status | grep -q running || service bormarise_celery_daemon start
```

Despite being a bit long, it should only try to run the start command if the `bormarise_celery_daemon` service isn't running.

## service vs initctl

While the `service` command makes an attempt to manage Upstart jobs, it is not the actual Upstart control function -- that would be `initctl` and the related suite of short-hand commands (*i.e.*, `start`, `stop`, *etc.*). All of the Upstart scripts reside in `/sbin/`.

The `service` command tries to facilitate people spreading services between both Upstart and classic SysV-style scripts. That way you can use one interface (the `service` script) to manage services from both systems.

## Delving into the service Script

If you browse the actual source of the `service` script (it's just a Bash script) on Ubuntu 14.04, you'll see:

```
if [ -r "/etc/init/${SERVICE}.conf" ] && which initctl >/dev/null \
   && initctl version | grep -q upstart
then
   # Upstart configuration exists for this job and we're running on upstart
   case "${ACTION}" in
      start|stop|status|reload)
         # Action is a valid upstart action
         exec ${ACTION} ${SERVICE} ${OPTIONS}
      ;;
      restart)
         # Map restart to the usual sysvinit behavior.
         stop ${SERVICE} ${OPTIONS} || :
         exec start ${SERVICE} ${OPTIONS}
      ;;
      force-reload)
         # Upstart just uses reload for force-reload
         exec reload ${SERVICE} ${OPTIONS}
      ;;
   esac
fi
```

The opening conditional:

1. Checks if the service you specified (in your case: `bormarise_celery_daemon`) is an Upstart job. Upstart jobs go into `/etc/init/` with a `.conf` extension.
2. If it is, the `service` script will check to see if it can run `initctl`.
3. If it can, the `service` script will then make sure that `initctl` is a new-enough version.

If all of that is true, then the `service` script will try to use the appropriate `initctl` command to run the Upstart job. For example:

```
service bormarise_celery_daemon start
```

translates into:

```
start bormarise_celery_daemon
```

which is (basically) equivalent to:

```
initctl start bormarise_celery_daemon
```

**However**, if any of those conditions is not true, the `service` script assumes you're trying to run a SysV-style script. These are just Bash scripts located in `/etc/init.d/`. However, if no such script exists, it will exit with the `unrecognized service` error message.

## Putting the Pieces Together

The default `PATH` for cron only contains `/bin/` and `/usr/bin/`. This means it doesn't include `/sbin/` which is where the `initctl` executable is. **This means `cron` will not be able to run `initctl`.**

When `cron` runs your crontab, the `service` script **is** able to find your Upstart job, but it is **not** able to run the `initctl` command, so it skips over trying to run your service via Upstart (*i.e.*, `initctl`). Instead, it then tries to look for a SysV-style script in `/etc/init.d/`. Since that script doesn't exist, the `service` script gives up and prints your error message.

If you override `cron`'s default `PATH` with one including `/sbin/`, then the `service` script will be able to find `initctl` and will attempt to launch your Upstart job.

---

Interestingly, on Ubuntu 12.04 the `service` script only checks to see if an Upstart job exists, omitting both `initctl` checks. That means if you were trying this on Ubuntu 12.04, it would attempt to use Upstart to start your service. However, if `/sbin/` isn't on the path, it would fail with a (slightly) more intelligible error message:

```
/usr/bin/service: 123: exec: start: not found
```

Comment: grep -q with || is very clever. TIL. Thank you!